# chrome.Storage.local.get unable to get proper results?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to save a variables data to local storage, but after .get() call console-output is "1 result[object Object]" and in "2 result[object Object]".

```
function save_data(key_name, data){
console.log(key_name + '    '+ data);
var obj = {};
obj[key_name] = data;
chrome.storage.local.set(obj);
}


function load_data(key_name){
   chrome.storage.local.get('key_name', function(result){
     console.log('1 result' + result);
     //console-output:"1 result[object Object]"
   });
   chrome.storage.local.get(key_name, function(result){
     console.log('2 result' + result);
     //console-output:"2 result[object Object]"
   });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with type casting. You are trying to add an object to a string, which is the same as using the `toString()` method on an object which will always output `"[object Object]"`.

Instead of adding them, use a comma like so:

```
console.log('1 result',result);
```

There is a pretty good resource for info about types in javascript [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp).